# replace loading a file to a list with command line/shell version in python

Tags: python

Hi is there a way to load a file as such, but from command line

so i can type python test.py data.txt

instead of

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("/home/user/data.txt",  "rb").readlines()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
data = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[1],  "rb")]
```

No need for `.readlines()`, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a parameter to your script from the command line you would want to utilize [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput).

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
>   is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
>   full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c
>   command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string
>   '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0]
>   is the empty string.

**fileinput:**

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:],
>   defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. If a filename is '-', it
>   is also replaced by sys.stdin. To specify an alternative list of
>   filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file
>   name is also allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module. It is fairly easy to use and even allows you to directly supply and open files from the command line arguments.